# How to define resolver for dependencies from custom repository on GitHub?

Tags: playframework, sbt

Play 2.3 and sbt 0.13.5 for some reason following from play's `build.sbt` isn't recognized. And it's not pulling down this particular dependency. Any idea?

```
libraryDependencies += "elasticplay" % "elastic-search-module_2.10" % "1.0.0"

resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Repository", url("https://github.com/vikasdp/elasticplay/tree/master/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

And it throws the following

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.vikasdp.elasticplay#elastic-search-module_2.10;1.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.vikasdp.elasticplay#elastic-search-module_2.10;1.0.0: not found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:    com.vikasdp.elasticplay#elastic-search-module_2.10;1.0.0: not found
```

**Update:**

The following output is shown when running `activator publishLocal` in `elastic-search-module` project:

```
  elastic-search-module vpandya$ activator publishLocal
  [info] Loading project definition from /Users/vpandya/elastic-search-module/project
  [info] Set current project to elastic-search-module (in build   file:/Users/vpandya/elastic-search-module/)
 [info] Wrote /Users/vpandya/elastic-search-module/target/scala-2.10/elastic-  search-module_2.10-1.0.0.pom
 [info] :: delivering :: elasticplay#elastic-search-module_2.10;1.0.0 :: 1.0.0 :: release    :: Mon Aug 04 12:25:50 EDT 2014
 [info]     delivering ivy file to /Users/vpandya/elastic-search-module/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1.0.0.xml
 [info]     published elastic-search-module_2.10 to   /Users/vpandya/.ivy2/local/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/poms/elastic-search-  module_2.10.pom
 [info]     published elastic-search-module_2.10 to /Users/vpandya/.ivy2/local/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/jars/elastic-search-module_2.10.jar
 [info]     published elastic-search-module_2.10 to /Users/vpandya/.ivy2/local/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/elastic-search-module_2.10-sources.jar
 [info]     published elastic-search-module_2.10 to /Users/vpandya/.ivy2/local/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/docs/elastic-search-module_2.10-javadoc.jar
 [info]     published ivy to /Users/vpandya/.ivy2/local/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
 [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2014 12:25:50 PM
```

Running `sbt "show projectId"` on `elastic-search-module` shows the following:

```
elasticplay:elastic-search-module:1.0.0
```

**Update 2**

running `sbt "show libraryDependencies" "show resolvers"` in `elasticplay` module shows the following:

```
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.3.0,   org.scalatest:scalatest:2.1.5:test, org.scalacheck:scalacheck:1.11.3:test, org.scalatestplus:play:1.0.0:test, org.scalaz:scalaz-core:7.0.6)
[info] List()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** GitHub serves raw files from https://raw.githubusercontent.com (not https://github.com/) so `resolvers` should use the URL.

You've defined a Maven repository, but have a Ivy2 directory layout inside.

Change your repository layout to a Maven one - `com/vikasdp/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0` and place `elastic-search-module_2.10-1.0.0.jar` inside.

You can alternatively change the new `resolver` to an Ivy2 one with `Resolver.ivyStylePatterns` so it becomes - please note the URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`:

```
val url = url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vikasdp/elasticplay/master/releases")

resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Repository", url)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

See [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) in the official documentation of sbt.

With the build definition, sbt could resolve the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "elasticplay" % "elastic-search-module_2.10" % "1.0.0"
```

When you hit the issue that manifests itself as *invalid sha1* use the following to disable the verification of the checksums of the downloaded file(s) with the following:

```
checksums in update := Nil
```

See [Checksums](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#checksums) in the official documentation of sbt.

Comment: :thanks.that makes sense.however looks like am still missing something. `https://github.com/vikasdp/elasticplay/tree/master/releases/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0`is a new path.dependency is changed to `"elasticplay" % "elastic-search-module_2.10" % "1.0.0"` with `resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Repository", url("https://github.com/vikasdp/elasticplay/tree/master/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)`gives `problem while downloading module descriptor:`

Comment: https://github.com/vikasdp/elasticplay/tree/master/releases/elasticplay/elastic-search-module_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml: invalid sha1:

Comment: You may want to give `checksums` a try as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#checksums.

Comment: appears play 2.3 `activator` has changed something. To narrow this down, I am doing `activator publish-local` for `elasticplay` play module. And trying to refer locally published module, from another play(2.3) project. with `"elasticplay" % "elastic-search-module_2.10" % "1.0.0"` in `libraryDependencies`. it's not throwing any error but at the same time doesn't pull down this (`elasticplay`) dependency into the current project.

Comment: Could you execute `sbt "show projectId"` inside the `elastic-search-module` project that's aimed to give the proper ModuleID? Could you add the `activator publishLocal`'s output to the question to clarify it further?

Comment: added more details under update section in the question. appreciate your time in looking into this.

Comment: I don't see why it could be failing. Could you also add `sbt "show libraryDependencies" "show resolvers"` to display `libraryDependencies` and `resolvers` for the project?

Comment: Added `sbt "show libraryDependencies" "show resolvers"` in update 2 section in the question. Any idea?

Comment: Found it! You should be using another URL.